# M2 <sequence> issue. Unsure if it's a bug I should log

Tags: magento2

We're developing 10-12 internal M2 extension for a big corporate client.  These all load via Composer.  Developers had this  node in three of the extensions.

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
</sequence>
```

This caused our /app/etc/config.php array to be out of order with the primary effect being that Magento_Customer loaded before Magento_Theme and broke widget positioning  (I'm sure there were other issues but I didn't need to look any further).  Similar to this

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2214/2

After digging around for a day, I discovered a workaround was to remove

```
<module name="Magento_Backend"/>
```

from

```
<sequence>
```

in just one of the extensions.

I'm guessing we created a circular dependency and I've read that Magento will give up using the  positions if it discovers a circular dependency in bin/magento setup:upgrade but not sure why removing it from one of three made a difference.

In developer mode, I would've expected an entry in the logs but there wasn't anything.

I'd like to report it as a bug but not sure if it actually is one.

Has anyone else experienced their /app/etc/config.php being strangely out of order?

Thanks, Wilson